# MMX error A2022:instruction operands must be the same size

Tags: visual-studio, masm, mmx

I'm trying to handtune a piece of code(a function originally writen in C++) and the assembler throws this error:
  error A2022:instruction operands must be the same size

at the lines that use the 'movq' instruction.

The code:

```
.686P       
.mmx          
.xmm           
.MODEL flat, stdcall
.STACK 4096

.data
packedbytes db 10, 20, -30, 40, 50, 60, -70, 80
packedwords dw 10, 20, 30, 40
packeddwords dd 10, 20

.code
main PROC 

    movq mm0, packedbytes   ; <== error thrown here
    movq mm1, packedwords   ; <== here
    movq mm2, packeddwords  ; <== and here

    mov a0, 04d
    mov al, 0d  
    int 21h     
main ENDP
END main
```

I'm using masm on a 32 bit box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Instruction operands must be the same size" for MOVDQU from .data array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67423628/instruction-operands-must-be-the-same-size-for-movdqu-from-data-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. You can't use the registers directly; you can only place data via a pointer(at least with masm).

```
    mov edx, offset packedbytes
    movq mm0, [edx] 
    mov edx, offset packedwords
    movq mm1, [edx]
    mov edx, offset packeddwords   
    movq mm2, [edx]
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: You can use `qword ptr [packedbytes]` to override the default operand-size.  MASM doesn't suck *that* much.