# "Instruction operands must be the same size" for MOVDQU from .data array

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, sse

I have an .asm file with 2 arrays:

```
.DATA
compara byte 16 dup (?)
subtrai byte 16 dup (128)
```

Then I tried to use `movdqu` on the arrays (to `xmm1` and `xmm2`), but I'm having a problem.
Even though they are the same size, each array stores 16 bytes of data, I get the error:

> **error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size**

```
movdqu xmm2, compara
movdqu xmm1, subtrai
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MASM is talking about the size of one element (byte), not the total size of the array.  Just like if you wrote `mov eax, compara`, where you'd need `mov eax, dword ptr compara` to get it to emit a 4-byte load from an array of 1-byte elements, even if it was `byte 4 dup(?)`

```
movdqu xmm2, xmmword ptr [compara]
```

The square brackets are optional, but IMO good style to always use them for a memory operand.